# Run a large amount of tasks on a cluster

Tags: task, cluster-computing, mesos, apache-aurora

I'm looking for a solution to running a large amount of tasks and monitoring their status on a cluster.

In detail: Each task consists of 3-4 processes which are docker contained (each process is a docker run command). All of the processes have to run on the same server.

The amount of tasks we're talking about is bursts of several hundreds of tasks at a time.

I've looked into several solutions all of them based on Mesos:

- Chronos - Seems like it would falter under high load and in any case is more directed towards recurring (cron) jobs. While I need one-time (heavy) job.
- Custom Mesos FW - Seems to low-level for my needs would require me to write scheduling and retrying mechanisms, I'd save this for last resort.
- Aurora - This seems promising as each task is run on the same node and comprised of several processes. I am missing a couple of this here though: Aurora seems to not be able to run several tasks as a part of a single job. Since my tasks are all similar with different input I could use a single job with many (say 400) instances and the first process of each task (whose role is to download the input from S3) could download a different set based on the instance ID. Which brings me to another problem: I can't find a working example of using {{ mesos.instance }} in .aurora files can anyone give me an example?

Thanks for all the fish people

Answer (score 2):

You could also have a look on [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) (which also can be run as a [framework in Mesos](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos.md)). Kubernetes has the concept of [Pods](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/pods.html) which are basically a set of co-located containers. So in your case a pod would consist of your 3-4 processes/containers and then these pods can be scaled up/down.

Short comments regarding the other solutions you mentioned:

- Chronos: Not really targeting your use case
- Custom FW: Actually not so difficult, but good call to save this as last resort.
- Aurora: Very powerful but also complex framework
- [Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon) (which you didn't mention): targeted for long running applications which can be easily scaled up and down.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you
As for Marathon, I understand it's kind of init.d for Mesos.
I am not looking for a service but rather and app. So I didn't think it would fit.

Comment: Agree, just keep in mind if it is something of which you always want a small number of instances running and then burst at certain events (i.e. increase the number of instances) it could be interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent other answer, you could check out Two Sigma's [Cook](https://github.com/twosigma/Cook) which they have only recently open sourced but have been using in prod at scale for a while.

Comment: Good advice, I personally have not tested it so far :-). The co-location constraint seems to nicely map to kubernetes pods, didn't find whether cook has similar primitives.